# Recyclerview only displaying the first five items in a cursor

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, loader

I'm trying to populate a `recyclerview` with a `loader` but the adapter will only bind the first five items on the database and then repeat for every other item in the database.

To make it clear, it looks like this:

item 1

item 2

item 3

item 4

item 5

item 1

item 2

...

The number of items still matches the number of items on the database though. I've also tested the cursor and it prints every item correctly so I'm assuming the problem is the adapter. This is what I'm using:

```
class LibraryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LibraryAdapter.LibraryViewHolder> {

private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;

LibraryAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.mCursor = cursor;
    setHasStableIds(true);
}

static class LibraryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView titleText;
    private TextView numText;

    LibraryViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        titleText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.titleText);
        numText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.numText);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         ....
    }
}

@Override
public LibraryAdapter.LibraryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    return new LibraryViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(LibraryAdapter.LibraryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    LibraryModel item = getData(position);
    holder.titleText.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.numText.setText(item.getNum() + " items");
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (mCursor != null) ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;
}

private Cursor swapCursor(Cursor cursor){
    if(mCursor == cursor){
        return null;
    }
    Cursor oldCursor = mCursor;
    this.mCursor = cursor;
    if(cursor != null){
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    return oldCursor;
}

void changeCursor(Cursor cursor){
    Cursor oldCursor = swapCursor(cursor);
    if (oldCursor != null){
        oldCursor.close();
    }
}

private LibraryModel getData(int position){
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    String title = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry.COLUMN_TITLE));
    int num = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry.COLUMN_NUMBER));
    LibraryModel item = new LibraryModel();
    item.setTitle(title);
    item.setNum(num);
    return item;
}
}
```

And on the fragment:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_alltracks, container, false);
    libraryRecyclerview = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.list);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    libraryRecyclerview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
    mAdapter = new LibraryAdapter(getContext(), null, allTracks);
    libraryRecyclerview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return root;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(1, null, this);
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    Uri uri = DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = {
            DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry._ID,
            DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry.COLUMN_TITLE,
            DatabaseContract.LibraryEntry.COLUMN_NUM
    };
    return new CursorLoader(getContext(), uri, projection, null, null, null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(data);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

Comment: why to reinvent the wheel? why not to use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter?

Comment: @pskink well, good point.. I guess I just would like to understand why this one isn't working

Comment: add some `Log.d` calls inside `onBindViewHolder` then

Comment: @pskink I did that before posting, should have mentioned it. It prints the values of  `title` and `position` up to the 5th item then stops

Comment: how it stops?  i see you have more items than 5, are you sure your cursor is right? did your try DatabaseUtils#dumpCursor?

Answer (score 4):

For anyone still stumbling into this question:

I had the same problem, repeating the same 5 entries in my recycler view.

What fixed my problem was simply to remove

```
adapter.setHasStableIds(true)
```

Granted, this got me up to other problems, but I managed to display all my entries with this.

Comment: This is great! I was trying to implement checkbox animations (hide/reveal) for all the items inside the RecyclerView, it was so messed up before, it's all looking good now, thanks!